# Could not find implicit value for parameter F: cats.Applicative[F] with Sync and Temporal

Tags: scala, monads, implicit, cats-effect

Basically, I just want to add a `sleep` somewhere, but I don't understand how to provide the implicit Applicative needed.

I'm using cats effect 3.5.
It's totally new to me.
I have been using ZIO for 2 years, but I'm lost about how to jungle with the generic wrappers in cats effect.

Let's consider a basic code of a heath-check route, for example:

```scala
class Routes[F[_]: Sync] extends Http4sDslExt[F, Nothing] {
  import Routes._

  val routes: HttpRoutes[F] = HttpRoutes.of {
    case (HEAD | GET) -> Root / PathPrefix => Response[F]().withStatus(Ok).pure[F]
  }

}
```

I naively tried to add `Temporal` and do a `sleep` like this:

```scala
class Routes[F[_]: Sync: Temporal] extends Http4sDslExt[F, Nothing] {
  import Routes._

  val routes: HttpRoutes[F] = HttpRoutes.of {
    case (HEAD | GET) -> Root / PathPrefix =>
      for {
        resp <- Response[F]().withStatus(Ok).pure[F] // No implicits found for parameter F: Applicative[F]
        _ <- Temporal[F].sleep(5.seconds)
      } yield resp
  } // No implicits found for parameter Monad $F$0F: Monad[F_]
```

Should I define and provide an Applicative that implements both Sync and Temporal?
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because both `Sync` and `Temporal` extend `Applicative` (indirectly). So when the compiler tries to find `Applicative[F]`, it has two unrelated instances in scope - `Sync[F]` and `Temporal[F]`. It doesn't have any way to decide between them, so it fails to find the implicit.

In this case the code doesn't need `Sync` at all, so you can remove it:

```
class Routes[F[_]: Temporal]
```

If the code did need to use both constraints, then it could use `Async[F]` instead, which extends both `Sync` and `Temporal`, providing both capabilities

```
class Routes[F[_]: Async]
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by using only `Temporal`:

```scala
class Routes[F[_]: Temporal]
```

It makes sense that a synchronous effect is not expected to wait, but I would be happy to have more advanced explanations.